# How to add a DatePicker to Tableview with a DatePickerCell

Tags: datepicker, javafx-2, javafx, tableview

I've add a DatePicker to a TableView with the following class : https://code.google.com/p/javafx-filterable-table-columns/source/browse/src/main/java/thirdparty/eu/schudt/javafx/controls/calendar/DatePicker.java?r=db47db237b3342712aafb693f392d403455d5299

I use a DatePickerCell class to ovveride TableCell. The DatePicker display well in the TableView. But the updateItem method does not work well, it does not update the ObservableList.

What am I missing here? Can anyone faced same problem?

Here is my code :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Locale;  
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;  
import javafx.geometry.Pos;  
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;  
import thirdparty.eu.schudt.javafx.controls.calendar.DatePicker;  

public class DatePickerCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {  

    private final DatePicker datePicker;  
    private ObservableValue<T> ov;  
    public DatePickerCell() {  
        // Initialize the DatePicker for birthday  
        this.datePicker = new DatePicker(Locale.ENGLISH);  
        this.datePicker.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));  
        this.datePicker.getCalendarView().todayButtonTextProperty().set("Today");  
        this.datePicker.getCalendarView().setShowWeeks(false);          
        this.datePicker.getStylesheets().add("styles/DatePicker.css");  
        this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);  
        this.setGraphic(this.datePicker);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {  
        super.updateItem(item, empty);  
        setGraphic(this.datePicker);  
    }  
}
```

And the part of cellFactory in the FXController code :

```
@FXML  
private TableColumn revueDateCol;  

this.revueDateCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Revue, Date>, TableCell<Revue, Date>>() {  
        @Override  
        public TableCell<Revue, Date> call(TableColumn<Revue, Date> arg0) {  
            return new DatePickerCell<>();  
        }  
   });
```

Thank for help.

---

I've tried to implements this way but when I scroll, the cell return to the original value. 
Any idea ?

```
public class DatePickerCell<S, T> extends TableCell<Revue, Date> {

    private DatePicker datePicker;

    public DatePickerCell() {
        if (datePicker == null) {
            createDatePicker();
        }        
        setGraphic(datePicker);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                datePicker.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Date item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
        if (datePicker != null) {
               datePicker.setSelectedDate(getDate());
        }

            setGraphic(this.datePicker);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }
    }

    private void createDatePicker() {
        datePicker = new DatePicker(Locale.FRENCH);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        datePicker.setDateFormat(formatter);
        datePicker.setPromptText("jj/mm/aaaa");
        datePicker.getCalendarView().todayButtonTextProperty().set("Aujourd'hui");
        datePicker.getCalendarView().setShowWeeks(false);
        datePicker.getStylesheets().add("/styles/datePicker.css");

        datePicker.selectedDateProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<Date>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Date> observable,
                            Date oldValue, Date newValue) {

                        commitEdit(newValue);
                    }
                });

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    private Date getDate() {
        return datePicker.getSelectedDate() != null ? datePicker.getSelectedDate() : getItem();
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that work. It uses a DatePicker and TableView control with Java 8.
The blog post is available [here](http://blog.physalix.com/javafx8-render-a-datepicker-cell-in-a-tableview/).

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;

public class DatePickerCell<S, T> extends TableCell<BirthdayEvent, Date> {

    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private ObservableList<BirthdayEvent> birthdayData;

    public DatePickerCell(ObservableList<BirthdayEvent> listBirthdays) {

        super();

        this.birthdayData = listBirthdays;

        if (datePicker == null) {
            createDatePicker();
        }
        setGraphic(datePicker);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                datePicker.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Date item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        SimpleDateFormat smp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        if (null == this.datePicker) {
            System.out.println("datePicker is NULL");
        }

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {

            if (isEditing()) {
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

            } else {
                setDatepikerDate(smp.format(item));
                setText(smp.format(item));
                setGraphic(this.datePicker);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setDatepikerDate(String dateAsStr) {

        LocalDate ld = null;
        int jour, mois, annee;

        jour = mois = annee = 0;
        try {
            jour = Integer.parseInt(dateAsStr.substring(0, 2));
            mois = Integer.parseInt(dateAsStr.substring(3, 5));
            annee = Integer.parseInt(dateAsStr.substring(6, dateAsStr.length()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("setDatepikerDate / unexpected error " + e);
        }

        ld = LocalDate.of(annee, mois, jour);
        datePicker.setValue(ld);
    }

    private void createDatePicker() {
        this.datePicker = new DatePicker();
        datePicker.setPromptText("jj/mm/aaaa");
        datePicker.setEditable(true);

        datePicker.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            public void handle(Event t) {
                LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue();
                int index = getIndex();

                SimpleDateFormat smp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getDayOfMonth());
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonthValue() - 1);
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear());

                setText(smp.format(cal.getTime()));
                commitEdit(cal.getTime());

                if (null != getBirthdayData()) {
                    getBirthdayData().get(index).setDate(cal.getTime());
                }
            }
        });

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    public ObservableList<BirthdayEvent> getBirthdayData() {
        return birthdayData;
    }

    public void setBirthdayData(ObservableList<BirthdayEvent> birthdayData) {
        this.birthdayData = birthdayData;
    }

    public DatePicker getDatePicker() {
        return datePicker;
    }

    public void setDatePicker(DatePicker datePicker) {
        this.datePicker = datePicker;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the tableView editable, you need to
`tableView.setEditable(true)`.
override the `startEdit()`, `cancelEdit()` methods of `TableCell`.
set the `revueDateCol.setOnEditCommit()` of the related `TableColumn`.
invoke `commitEdit()` when editing has been finished.

The working example is [official tutorial for Table View](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm), Example 12-11: Alternative Solution Of Cell Editing.
The first three steps above are almost identical, except that you will be using DatePicker instead of TextField.
The last step can be as:

```
private void createTextField() {
    datePicker = new DatePicker(Locale.ENGLISH);
    datePicker.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    datePicker.getCalendarView().todayButtonTextProperty().set("Today");
    datePicker.getCalendarView().setShowWeeks(false);
    datePicker.getStylesheets().add("styles/DatePicker.css");
    datePicker.selectedDateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Date>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Date> observable, Date oldValue, Date newValue) {
            commitEdit(newValue);
        }
    });
}
```